# Django not displaying correct URL after reverse

Tags: django, urlconf

There's lots of documentation about Django and the `reverse()` method. I can't seem to locate my exact problem. Suppose I have two urlconfs like this:

```
url(r'ParentLists/$', main_page, name = "main_page"),
url(r'ParentLists/(?P<grade_level>.+)/$', foo, name = "foo")
```

and the two corresponding views like this:

```
def main_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        grade_level = request.POST['grade_picked']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foo', args = (grade_level,)))

    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html', context = {'grade_list' : grade_list})

def foo(request, grade_level):

    grade_level = request.POST['grade_picked']

    parent_list = # get stuff from database
    emails      = # get stuff from database

    return render(request, 'list.html', context = {'grade_list' : grade_list, 'parent_list' : parent_list})
```

Here, `list.html` just extends my base template `index.html`, which contains a drop down box with grade levels. When the user goes to **/ParentLists**, the `main_page` view renders index.html with the drop down box as it should.

When the user picks a grade level from the drop down box (say 5th Grade), the template does a form submit, and `main_page` once again executes - but this time the POST branch runs and the `HttpResponseRedirect` takes the user to **/ParentLists/05**. This simply results in an HTML table pertaining to grade 5 being displayed below the drop down box.

The problem is, when the user now selects say 10th Grade, the table updates to show the grade 10 content, but the URL displayed is still **/ParentLists/05**. I want it to be **/ParentLists/10**.

Clearly, after the first selection, the `main_page` view never executes again. Only `foo` does...and so the `HttpResponseRedirect` never gets called. How should I reorganize this to get what I'm looking for? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly mentioned you will never redirect to foo() from foo().

So the simple way to fix this is just add similar code as in main_page() view:

```
def foo(request, grade_level):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        grade_level = request.POST['grade_picked']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foo', args = (grade_level,)))
    else:
        parent_list = # get stuff from database
        emails      = # get stuff from database

        return render(request, 'list.html', context = {'grade_list' : grade_list, 'parent_list' : parent_list})
```

Please note that I remove `grade_level = request.POST['grade_picked']` because as Nagkumar Arkalgud correctly said it is excessively.

Also instead of combination of `HttpResponseRedirect` and `reverse` you can use shortcut `redirect` which probably little easy to code:

```
from django.shortcuts redirect
...
return redirect('foo', grade_level=grade_level)
```

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you. I will take a look at it again this afternoon and see if your suggestions help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use kwargs instead of args.
The right way to use the view is:

```
your_url = reverse("<view_name>", kwargs={"<key>": "<value>"})
```

Ex:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foo', kwargs={"grade_level": grade_level}))
```

Also, you are sending "grade_level" to your view foo using the URL and not a POST value. I would remove the line:

```
grade_level = request.POST['grade_picked']
```

as you will override the grade_level sent to the method from the url.